# Android Studio palette lost

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner and I am using Android Java Studio. I have closed my GUI Interface and palette tab and now I can't find a way to get it back. Could you tell me how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look over on the right, you should see Preview. Click it (assuming you have a layout open in the editor tab).

[image]

Comment: I have no files open ://

Comment: You want to see the GUI interface. To do that: 1. go find the layout you want to work on (under src/main/res/layout), e.g. myActivityLayout.xml, 2. double click that to open it, then 3. (if that did not open the Preview pane), look for the preview view indicator and click it.

Comment: Thank you very much, i have been struggling for an hour to find that

Comment: You're welcome, that's what this site is for: to lessen needless suffering. :)

Comment: But i dont see a phone, where i can put items on

Comment: Dude, this site is to answer specific questions. You lost the preview pane, that's what the title says. Accept my answer (how this site works) then if you can't figure out how to use the gui editor, post another question about that. I will help. I have many android apps with a ton of views and fragments and know the gui editor very well.

Comment: It says - "Missing styles.Is this the correct theme chosen for this layout?"

Comment: Did you figure this out? I wouldn't think a missing style would make the view not render at all?